# jquery after calling ajax, change several input fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, select, input

I have problem with jquery ajax request:

I have one select field and after more then one input fields.

After changing select field, ajax.php get some informations from Database in separate files.
How can I call back those values and set it into previos input fields?

I know how to call all values back, and set them in , but not how to set values in separate input fields (data_1, data_2, data_3)

```
<select name="call_ajax" id="call_ajax">
    <input type="text" value="1">Value 1
    <input type="text" value="2">Value 2
</select>

<input type="text" id="data_1" value="some old data 1">
<input type="text" id="data_2" value="some old data 2">
<input type="text" id="data_3" value="some old data 3">

<script>
    $("#call_ajax").change(function() {
         $.ajax
            ({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(html)
              {                 
              $("#what").html(html); // ???????  

              } 
            }); 
    });
</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php 
$new_data1 = "new value 1";
$new_data2 = "new value 2";
$new_data3 = "new value 3";
 ?>
```

Comment: `ajax.php` should return the data in a structured format, e.g. JSON (for preference), XML, CSV, etc.  If you return JSON the parameter of the `success: function` should be an object that you can query

Answer (score 1):

Currently your PHP script returns an empty page - no input for the Ajax process. You need to output some data with your PHP script, for example in a JSON format:

```
<?php 
$new_data1 = "new value 1";
$new_data2 = "new value 2";
$new_data3 = "new value 3";
echo json_encode(array("data_1"=>$new_data1,
                       "data_2"=>$new_data2,
                       "data_3"=>$new_data3));
?>
```

This would return the following:

```
{"data_1":"new value 1","data_2":"new value 2","data_3":"new value 3"}
```

Your script could then use this information like

```js
// sample data:
var dat={"data_1":"new value 1","data_2":"new value 2","data_3":"new value 3"};

$("#call_ajax").change(function() {
  /*  $.getJSON("ajax.php",
                function(dat){  */
              
              // inside the callback do the following with dat:
              
              $("input:text").each(function(){
                 this.value=dat[this.id]; })
                
              
/*    });     */
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="call_ajax" id="call_ajax">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="data_1" value="some old data 1">
<input type="text" id="data_2" value="some old data 2">
<input type="text" id="data_3" value="some old data 3">
```

Also, please note that there can be no `<input>` elements inside a `<select>` element. Use `<option>` instead.